# Codename one BrowserComponent crash

Tags: codenameone

I have been developing an app that uses a payment gateway and I tried using a browserNavigation callback to execute some Java code when the return URL is loaded. My problem is that, the app crashes just before the for containing the browser component loads.

Below is the error it reports:

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x54c3249e, pid=28320, tid=31852

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b26) (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [jfxwebkit.dll+0x5d249e]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Users\MY_COMPUTER_NAME\IdeaProjects\My_APP_NAME\hs_err_pid28320.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the many JavaFX bugs in the JVM and webkit support... You do however have a very old version of the VM. I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Java 8 as some of those crashes were resolved.